# How to do peek operation in queue in C?

Tags: c, queue, peek

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define max 100

int enqueue();
int dequeue();
int peek();
void display();

int main()
{
      char name[max][80], data[80];
      int front, rear, value;
      int ch;
      front = rear = -1;
        printf("------------------------------\n");
        printf("\tMenu");
        printf("\n------------------------------");
        printf("\n [1] ENQUEUE");
        printf("\n [2] DEQUEUE");
        printf("\n [3] PEEK");
        printf("\n [4] DISPLAY");
      printf("\n------------------------------\n");
      while(1)
      {
            printf("Choice : ");
            scanf("%d", &ch);
            switch(ch)
            {
                  case 1 : // insert
                        printf("\nEnter the Name : ");
                        scanf("%s",data);
                        value = enqueue(name, &rear, data);
                        if(value == -1 )
                              printf("\n QUEUE is Full \n");
                        else
                              printf("\n'%s' is inserted in QUEUE.\n\n",data);
                        break;
                  case 2 : // delete
                        value = dequeue(name, &front, &rear, data);
                        if( value == -1 )
                              printf("\n QUEUE is Empty \n");
                        else
                              printf("\n Deleted Name from QUEUE is : %s\n", data);
                              printf("\n");
                        break;
                 case 3:
                    value = peek(name, &front, &rear, data);
                    if(value != -1)
                    {
                        printf("\n The front is: %s", value);
                    }
                        break;
                  case 5 : exit(0);
                  default: printf("Invalid Choice \n");
            }
      }
      return 0;
}

int enqueue(char name[max][80], int *rear, char data[80])
{
      if(*rear == max -1)
            return(-1);
      else
      {
            *rear = *rear + 1;
            strcpy(name[*rear], data);
            return(1);
      }
}
int dequeue(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
      if(*front == *rear)
            return(-1);
      else
      {
            (*front)++;
            strcpy(data, name[*front]);
            return(1);
      }
}
int peek(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80])
{
     if(*front == -1 || *front > *rear)
    {
        printf(" QUEUE IS EMPTY\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return data[*front];
    }
}
```

My Peek operation has a problem it does not print the first element.

For example, the user input one name, and when the user selects the peek operation, the program should print the first element, but my program always prints QUEUE IS EMPTY even though my queue is not empty.

The peek operation should print the first element of the queue.

Comment: `printf("\n The front is: %s", value);` --> `printf("\n The front is: %d", value);`: `value` is an `int` not a string.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I already changed it, but it still prints the same output which is the queue is empty.

Comment: You are not setting `front` on the first `enque`, so it stays at `-1`

Comment: Your function declarations are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `enqueue()` then `peek()` the variable `front` is still `-1` and it incorrectly says the queue is empty.

1. I suggest your treat front to rear as a half open interval with both initialized to 0, so it's empty if `*front == *rear`.
2. `peek()` need to populate data and return an integer (not `data[*front]` which is nonsense).
3. `main()` after `peek()` you need to print `data` not `value`.
4. Your prototypes are wrong.  If you move the functions before `main()` then you can remove them.

```
int enqueue(char name[max][80], int *rear, const char data[80]) {
    if(*rear + 1 == max)
        return -1;
    strcpy(name[*rear], data);
    (*rear)++;
    return 1;
}

int peek(char name[max][80], int *front, int *rear, char data[80]) {
    if(*front == *rear) {
        printf(" QUEUE IS EMPTY\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(data, name[*front]);
    return 1;
}

// ...

int main() {
    char name[max][80], data[80];
    int front = 0;
    int rear = 0;
    int value;
    int ch;
    printf("------------------------------\n");
    printf("\tMenu");
    printf("\n------------------------------");
    printf("\n [1] ENQUEUE");
    printf("\n [2] DEQUEUE");
    printf("\n [3] PEEK");
    printf("\n [4] DISPLAY");
    printf("\n------------------------------\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1 : // insert
                printf("\nEnter the Name : ");
                scanf("%s",data);
                value = enqueue(name, &rear, data);
                if(value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Full \n");
                else
                    printf("\n'%s' is inserted in QUEUE.\n\n",data);
                break;
            case 2 : // delete
                value = dequeue(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if( value == -1 )
                    printf("\n QUEUE is Empty \n");
                else
                    printf("\n Deleted Name from QUEUE is : %s\n", data);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                value = peek(name, &front, &rear, data);
                if(value != -1)
                {
                    printf("\n The front is: %s\n", data);
                }
                break;
            case 5 : exit(0);
            default: printf("Invalid Choice \n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example session:

```
------------------------------
        Menu
------------------------------
 [1] ENQUEUE
 [2] DEQUEUE
 [3] PEEK
 [4] DISPLAY
------------------------------
Choice : 1

Enter the Name : test

'test' is inserted in QUEUE.

Choice : 3

 The front is: test
```

Comment: The Peek operation is now okay, but my dequeue operation is now working well with these codes, it does not delete the first element, it deletes the second element in the queue.